# VB .Net and asp .net adding each item from dropdownlist to label not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label

I am trying to add each item from dropdownlist to label. Any guesses why it won't work. Thanks for your answers.

```
Dim labels(2) As Label
Public Sub AddItemsFromDropdownlistToLabel()
    DefineLabels()
    'Add Items From Dropdownlist1 to three lables
    For Each item As Object In DropDownList1.Items
        If LabelCount < 3 AndAlso LabelCount > 0 Then
            labels(LabelCount).Text = item.ToString
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub DefineLabels()
    labels(0) = label1
    labels(1) = label2
    labels(2) = label3
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you definining/populating `LabelCount`?

Comment: Can you define "won't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems

1: Since you're checking `LabelCount>0` `labels(0)` will never be populated.

2: You've not got anything incrementing for each item in the loop to advance the population of the labels array.

3: Each `item` in your drop down is an instance of `ListItem`. To get a anything useful out of that, you're best to use either `item.Text` or `item.Value`.

Comment: thanks, i knew something was wrong but couldn't put my finger on it. Though, I don't think 3rd point was necessary. I added LabelCount = LabelCount + 1 after labels(LabelCount).Text = item.ToString and then changed LabelCount > 0 to LabelCount > -1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `LabelCount` has a value of 0 and is not changing in the `for each`.
You could use instead:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to DropDownList1.Items.Count
    If i >= 3 Then Exit For
    labels(i).Text = DropDownList1.Items(i).ToString()
Next
```

I suppose `DropDownList1` is a ComboBox or similar.

Comment: Correct, but I can't mark 2 answers. Thanks for your response though. Wish I could upvote your answer.